# App keeps crashing when using startActivity(Intent) to go to next activity

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, persistence

I have a bug in my app where updating two root-level nodes in my Firebase Realtime Database at the same time is causing the app to mini-crash and the startActivity(Intent) fails and it goes back to the base Activity.

```
fun makeNewChannel(currentUser: String, channelname: String) {
    val memberkey = fb.child("/channel/$channelname/members").push().key.toString()

    val updateChannel = HashMap<String, Any?>()
    updateChannel.put("/channel/$channelname/members/$memberkey", currentUser)
    updateChannel.put("/channel/$channelname/name", channelname)

    val updateUser = HashMap<String, Any?>()
    updateUser.put("/user/$currentUser/channels/$channelname", memberkey)

    fb.updateChildren(updateUser)
    fb.updateChildren(updateChannel)}
```

If I comment out the updateUser, which is the one on a different node, the startActivity does not crash and the app smoothly transitions to the next activity. I hypothesize that this might be because of the listener on the /channel node, but I really have no idea.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted **mare than 350 lines of code** for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: In the future, please do not repost your question, but edit it instead, when you want to add more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63677620/startactivityintent-mini-crashes-and-reloads-back-to-the-previous-activity

Comment: Could you take a look at my update now?

Answer (score 0):

Change this...

```
val myIntent = Intent(this@ChannelListActivity, ChannelActivity::class.java)
        myIntent.putExtra("chan_name", channelList[index])
        Log.d(
        "toChannel2",
        "Clicked channel from channel list, moving to ChannelActivity"
        )
        startActivity(myIntent)
        finish()
```

To this...

```
val myIntent = Intent(this@ChannelListActivity, ChannelActivity::class.java)

        // // The myIntent.flags tells to clear/close the @CurrentFragment/@CurrentActivity and inflate/start @NextFragment/@NextActiviy
        myIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        Log.d(
        "toChannel2",
        "Clicked channel from channel list, moving to ChannelActivity"
        )
        startActivity(myIntent)
        finish()
```